# Owl Carousel Parallax scrolling or similar

Tags: jquery, css, carousel, parallax, owl-carousel

We have designed a slider for our company history page (see image). I've used Owl Carousel 2 and got it working other than the numbers in the background.

I currently have the 2012 behind the white box, when you scroll to the next slide the 2012 slides with the box and then the 2013 box will show 2013 behind it and so on.

However we really want it to work like the mockup we designed, when you scroll to the next slide the number would scroll along like a parallax effect.

Does anyone know how to get this to work either with the owl carousel or an alternative. Cant get it to work at all, any help would be great!

[image]

Comment: Any code you can share? What have you tried that doesn't work?

Comment: Sure, the link below shows what i have so far. Youll need to make the preview window larger so that it only displays one slide at a time to see what i have...

http://jsfiddle.net/o0tef7np/1/

Basically I want it to work like this but with the number for the next two slides to be behind and to the right of the box as the mockup above